# Alamofire: Cannot invoke 'URLRequest' with an argument list of type '(Method, NSURL)'

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am playing with the request router pattern, that looks something like this:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

static let baseURLString = "https://somewhere"

case DoSomething

var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
    let (method: Method, path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {
        switch self {
        case .DoSomething:
            var params = [String: AnyObject]()
            return (.GET, "/doSomething", params)
        }
    }()

    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path)

    let request = URLRequest(method, URL)  // <- ERROR HERE

    let encoding = ParameterEncoding.URL

    return encoding.encode(request, parameters: parameters).0
}
}
```

And I'm getting the aforementioned "Cannot invoke 'URLRequest' with an argument list of type '(Method, NSURL)'"

Looking at the method signature of URLRequest I see:

`func URLRequest(method: Method, URL: URLStringConvertible) -> NSURLRequest`

`NSURL` conforms to the `URLStringConvertible` protocol, so all should be good. But it isn't. Now, here is the strange part:

If I cut and paste URLRequest into the same file as my enum, adjust its name by making it URLRequestt (to avoid conflicting with the original), and use that function instead, then all the compiler errors go away.

I am have copied the Alamofire swift files into my project because I am targeting iOS 7, so that might also be a factor. I'm not using an embedded Framework.

So, my question is: why does this code throw a compiler error and why does simply copy/pasting/renaming the URLRequest function cause it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Alamofire as a framework within your project, you won't have visibility to the `URLRequest` function, because it is not `public`. You can either make it public (I'm not crazy about forking AFNetworking for something that trivial), or you can just implement a copy of this function in your module.

I experimented, though, using Alamofire source right within my project, and I see the same curious behavior you describe. But you can easily circumvent this, either by including a copy of this function within your source file (as you described) or just bypass it completely:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
request.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
```

Comment: You're right, it's not public. But then its default would be 'internal'. Because I've copied the Alamofire .swift files into my project (not as an embedded framework), would that not make it 'internal' with regards to my project and therefore accessible to all of my Swift code?

Comment: I've done some further investigation, if I rename URLRequest() to xURLRequest() *inside Alamofire.swift*, and then call that function... no problem. If I put another randomly-named function inside Alamofire.swift, again no problem using that. Is it possible that there is something uniquely special about URLRequest? How would I check that?

Comment: Aha. There *is* something special about URLRequest, I have just declared it as a symbol in my enum. That's likely taking precedence over the symbol in Alamofire.swift. I need it to conform to the `URLRequestConvertible` protocol. I'm willing to give up and declare a new function with a different name, but if there is a 'right' way to fix this, I'd like to find it.